# I Am new to MongoDB and have following query which needs to be queried over 50k data from a collection but it is taking more time to return data

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Sample document:

```json
  {
    "_id": "gJtkx4nKAdWphanzZ",
    "newsId": "1212",
    "newsTitle": "ab",
    "newsLink": "link",
    "companyId": "qwqq",
    "companyName": "LC",
    "deals": [
      {
        "dealId": "fdkQWobFJiwdHbRjD",
        "clusterId": "AutonomousAndSustbility"
      },
      {
        "dealId": "e2pPACebfwyeHE",
        "clusterId": "ModernConuction"
      }
    ],
    "users": [
      {
        "userId": "iChz62XNeMf",
        "isReadNotification": false
      },
      {
        "userId": "zHruHDkvF398",
        "isReadNotification": false
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": 1656473406,
    "newsPublishedAt": 16557696
  }
```

Code:

```
  let news=  NewsRoomCollection.aggregate(
      [
        {$unwind: "$deals"},
        {$unwind: "$users"}, 
        queryParams.filters,
        {$match:{ "users.userId": queryParams.userId }},
        {$group:{
          _id: "$_id",
          companyId : { $first: '$companyId' },
          companyName : { $first: '$companyName' },
          newsId: {$first: "$newsId"},
          newsTitle: {$first: "$newsTitle"},
          newsLink: {$first: "$newsLink"},
          newsPublishedAt: {$first: "$newsPublishedAt"},
          deals: {$push: "$deals"},
          users:{$push: "$users"}
        }},
      {
        $facet: {
          "data": [
            { $sort:  queryParams.sortQuery },
            { $skip: skip },
            { $limit: limit },
          ],
          "pagination": [
            { $count: "total" }
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
  ).toArray();
```

I am not much aware about how to use `$group` and `$facet` together but it is returning correct data and taking more time when thousands of data's are present in collection

Please let me know that above query cause any performance issue or is it fine Thanks in advance

Here I need to match with 4 fields like `userId`, `newsPublishedAt`, `dealId`, `clusterId` and except for `userId` all other fields are dynamically coming from other place so am taking them in object.

Below query i am taking from other place like i have multiple queries and i have assigned them to a variable and passing to the main query.

```
   {
        $match:{ $and:[
            { "deals.dealId":{ $in :  selectedDeals }},
            { newsPublishedAt:{ $gte : newsFromDate, $lte: newsToDate }},
            {"deals.clusterId": {$in: selectedClusters }},
        ]}
    }
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: `$unwind` and `$group` might be pointless. Note, operator `$first` works also on arrays, you don't have to unwind the documents.

Comment: Please provide sample input documents and desired output.

Comment: {
  "_id": "gJtkx4nKAdWphanzZ",
  "newsId": "1212",
  "newsTitle": "ab",
  "newsLink": "link",
  "companyId": "qwqq",
  "companyName": "LC",
  "deals": [
    {
      "dealId": "fdkQWobFJiwdHbRjD",
      "clusterId": "AutonomousAndSustbility"
    },
    {
      "dealId": "e2pPACebfwyeHE",
      "clusterId": "ModernConuction"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": "iChz62XNeMf",
      "isReadNotification": false
    },
    {
      "userId": "zHruHDkvF398",
      "isReadNotification": false
    },

  ],
  "createdAt": 1656473406
  "newsPublishedAt": 16557696
}

Comment: When you don't use $match in the first line, your query doesn't use indexes, then the aggregate does a full-table scan. If possible, move all $match to the first line of your pipeline. You can use Explain command to see the analytics of your query.

Comment: As is, your `{$unwind: "$deals"}` and `{$unwind: "$users"}` will duplicate entries in the `"$group"` `deals: {$push: "$deals"}` unless `queryParams.filters` somehow explicitly "blocks" them.  Are you sure that even "as is" the returned document is what you want?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I need to get the document as is and am using this deals: {$push: "$deals"} bcoz after i got the data i am looping it for other purpose

Comment: @Naveenhm Have a look at this [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wAA25IimLtf) representation of your example data and aggregation pipeline. I filled in some values where you have variables, and notice that in the result `"users"` array there are duplicated elements.  I doubt you want that.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have seen the query you have written and the same query I have written,
I am not much sure that this query causing performance issue.

"notice that in the result "users" array there are duplicated elements. I doubt you want that."  no duplicate users are not required but still it pushing into an array

Comment: @RicardoAragão Actually whatever the fields i have used in $match those are  not indexed I mean those fields are like filters( am not used primary key in $match to compare).

Comment: @Naveenhm So, to make it clear, would you edit your question and show the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

As said, you may skip `$unwind` and `$group`. Would this be sufficient?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "users.userId": "zHruHDkvF398" } },
  {
    $set: {
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.userId", "zHruHDkvF398" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      pagination: { $size: "$users" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UQeoVNPDkwf)

Comment: Actually I need to match conditions for 4 fields like userId,dealId,clusterId,newsPublishedAt and here the complex thing is that dealId,clusterId,newsPublishedAt are combinations like user can put filter only for dealId and clusterId or dealId and newsPublishedAt or all the three, and also i need to sort based  on newsPublishedAt and isReadNotification, so this is the issue like how do i query for that.

Comment: $set is used to update the collection right?

Comment: `$set` updates the **output** of aggregation query. Existing collection data is not modified by this, it's a read-only operation.

Comment: yes, i was bit confused by reading the docs.